# format jquery timepicker to load into django TimeField

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms

I have a problem formatting my [jquery timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/). My problem is that I want to have the time show up in HH:MM AM/PM format in the form (so the user can see it that way), but load as military time (%H:%M) into the timefield. My formfield looks like this:

```
    if isinstance(f, models.TimeField):
    formfield.widget.format = '%H:%M'
    formfield.widget.attrs.update({'class':'timepicker', 'readonly':'true'})
```

I'm using Postgresql with `time without time zone` type. The jquery (from the link above) looks is this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
            $( ".timepicker" ).timepicker({
                showPeriod: true,
                showLeadingZero: true
            });
     });
 </script>
```

If I don't use showPeriod and showLoadingZero, it works fine, but it's not as user friendly as I'd like.

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm using the templating system, so my html for that field looks like this:

```
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.starttime.errors }} 
    <label for="id_starttime">Start Time:</label> 
    {{ form.starttime }} 
    </div>
```

Comment: I ran into something similar, jquery datepicker, they way I made it work was declaring the format in the HTML form, like this:
<input  type="text" name="some_name" data-date-format="mm/dd/yy" id="some_id">

Comment: Hi PepPizza - would the id then override the jquery id? Not having success implementing this right now.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [this timepicker](https://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/) instead, but had a similar problem.

In my forms.py, I changed

`def make_custom_datefield(f):
    formfield = f.formfield()
    if isinstance(f, models.TimeField):
        formfield.widget.format = '%H:%M'
        formfield.widget.attrs.update({'class':'timepicker', 'readonly':'true'})`

to

`time_widget = forms.widgets.TimeInput(attrs={'class': 'timepicker', 'readonly':'true'})
time_widget.format = '%I:%M %p'`

Then, in my form class, I have

`class DonationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    time = forms.TimeField(input_formats=['%I:%M %p'],widget=time_widget)
    ...`

Also be sure to note your format mask `'%H'` does not work with `'%p'` so use `'%I'` instead.

I have no idea why the other way was not working, or if this workaround is proper, but it seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps all you need to do is show as `HH:MM AM/PM` across the site, and let the `TimeField` take care of how it's stored in the database.  If you're happy with that, you can just use the following setting:

```
# settings.py

...

TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%I:%M %p']
```

For more info, see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#time-input-formats).